# Extending TreeMap to only take Integer -> Integer mappings?

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I want to make a class that is an extension of `TreeMap` that is only able to map integers to integers. Is there a better way to do this than simply casting everything to an `Integer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring your class as

```
class MyTreeMap extends TreeMap<Integer, Integer> {
```

Notice that `MyTreeMap` does not have any type parameters, since we know we only want to deal with `Integer`s.

Comment: i really don't see the point of doing this. ok Ryan Yu stated the question that way, but the question doesn't give a additional reason to do this instead of just using generics, and as long as there is no additional reason i wouldn't create a subclass. i would recommend Matt Balls answer.

Comment: @cproinger There can be reasons to do this... if you want to change some aspect of `TreeMap`'s functionality, or have it implement another interface. You can't assume it's pointless without knowing more about the OP's predicament.

Comment: sure. but there is none in the question. changing some aspect of TreeMap's functionality could break the semantics of TreeMap but MyTreeMap would still be assignable to TreeMap ... well i'm not trying to say it is generally wrong, but from my experience more often then not you're shooting yourself in the foot by extending from collection-classes (there's not enough context in the question to know but think about if you wanted to persist the object with hibernate).

Comment: Yeah, I'll explain a little, I guess: I was trying to map the size of a container -> number of occurrences of that size, but wanted to add some additional functionality in terms of manipulating the k/v pairs (i.e. pollAndDecrementLastKey, which decrements the count of a containerSize.) To implement this class, I wanted to restrict the keys and values in the pairs to just Integers.

Comment: so like TreeMap<Integer = Size, Integer = NumberOfOccurences>? what about concurrency? Collections.synchronizedCollection(.) won't work with a subclass. encapsulation seems the better approach in that way (like Woot4Moo's answer, only i wouldn't expose the whole Map-interface by implementing+delegating, just the things i'd need)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to extend or cast anything. [Use generics:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> foo = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

...and you're done.

Comment: eh I don't think this truly answers OP's issue.  What you have done is create an instance of a TreeMap that can only take Integers, what you have failed to do is create a specific TreeMap data structure that can ONLY take Integers.

Comment: @Woot4Moo not sure I see the point, but fair enough. That feels very pre-generic collections.

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to consider is implementing the Map interface like so:

```
class MyIntegerMap implements Map<Integer,Integer>  
{  
     private TreeMap<Integer,Integer> internalTreeMap;  
     ...  


    public Integer put(Integer key, Integer value)  
     {  
          interalTreeMap.put(key,value);
     }  
}
```

What this does is allow you to utilize the already defined TreeMap functions (avoiding all of the issues with performance if you hand rolled) and it allows you to restrict the valid input types of subclasses.